# Static Factory Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, d

The following code is a sort of factory pattern for D using templates that is meant making pluggable objects effortless.

As is, the code is not robust(multiple inheritance, dependencies, etc).

I'd like the ability for it to work in a more general and common setting such as having some type of dependency list for the different objects/types(I've setup the code to go along that path using a gui and button scenario).

I also think that there is probably some way to handle the saving and restoring of data easier but I'm not quite sure how to approach it. Would it be better to have each object serialize it's data and store it in a database or have a single global store that handles it all? (I think storing only the changes from a the default are whats important)

Anyways, maybe someone has some useful ideas to get me in the right direction?

(as is the code works nearly identical to using a factory as any implementation of iGui can be plugged in. I call it the static factory pattern simply because all the setup is done behind the scenes mostly at compile time(through the templates))

```
module main;
import std.file, std.stdio;

// Mixin iStaticFactory into an interface to provide generic pluggable derived instantiation. 
// Must use New(id, data) as a way to instantiate a new object of type A(specified by ID) : T. New() is allowed but only provides
// default type and is not pluggable. A msg is given anywhere New() is used(should only be used when pluggability is not desired) or during mock up.
//
// The corresponding mixin template cStaticFactory must be used in all derived types that are to be pluggable.
//
// The user must provide a way to store and retrieve the object data to allow generic and configurable pluggability. As is,
// any derived type of T may be substituted for T dynamically.
//
// D is the default object type to use
mixin template iStaticFactory(D) 
{
    alias T = typeof(this);
    static assert(is(D : typeof(this)), "iStaticFactory: "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(D)~" must inherit from "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(typeof(this)));

    @property string _getID();                                  // returns the type name for this object
    static final T function(string data)[string] _Creators;     // An AA of functions that are registered by the classes which are desired to be plugged into the interface T. 

    // Generic New function that returns an initiated instance of a derived type of T corresponding to data.ID.
    static final T New(string file = __FILE__, size_t line = __LINE__, string mod = __MODULE__)(string id, string data = null)
    {
        if (id != null && id in _Creators) return _Creators[id](data);
        return D.New(null); // provides default type
    }

    // Non-Generic New function returning a default derived type of T used for testing purposes or default object
    static final T New(string file = __FILE__, size_t line = __LINE__, string mod = __MODULE__)()
    {
        pragma(msg, "StaticFactory: Not pluggable at "~mod~":"~std.string.chomp(line.stringof, "u")~" ["~file~"]");
        return New(null);
    }
}

// Mixin cStaticFactory into any class to provide pluggability.
mixin template cStaticFactor()
{
    alias A = typeof(this);
    // Assume if A has a _Creators member, New member, and _getID member then it inherits from an interface using iStaticFactory
    static assert(std.traits.hasMember!(A, "_Creators") & std.traits.hasMember!(A, "New") & std.traits.hasMember!(A, "_getID"), "cStaticFactory: "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(A)~" must inherit from a Static Factory!");

    enum _ID = std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!A;
    @property string _getID() { return _ID; }

    // Registers this class with the _Creators of T's StaticFactory allowing it to be used to create it's own type. 
    static this() { A._Creators[_ID] = &New; }

    // Creates and instantiates this type with data. Override to instantiate data.
    static final T New(string data) { A t = new A; if (data == null) return t; return t; }
}



// Demo:
interface iGui { mixin iStaticFactory!(WindowsGui); void foo(); }
class WindowsGui : iGui { mixin cStaticFactor; void foo() { writeln("-------Called from "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(typeof(this))); } }
class LinuxGui : iGui { mixin cStaticFactor; void foo() { writeln("-------Called from "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(typeof(this))); } }

interface iButton { mixin iStaticFactory!(WindowsButton); void foo(); }
class WindowsButton : iButton { mixin cStaticFactor; void foo() { writeln("-------Called from "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(typeof(this))); } }
class LinuxButton : iButton { mixin cStaticFactor; void foo() { writeln("-------Called from "~std.traits.fullyQualifiedName!(typeof(this))); } }

void main()
{

    import std.traits;
    enum fnGui = "guiSFdata.tmp";
    enum fnButton = "butSFdata.tmp";

    // load/create our gui object. 
    iGui a = iGui.New(exists(fnGui) ? cast(string)read(fnGui, 100) : null); 


    // Display object's typeDo something with the object
    writeln("Current object type is "~a._getID~"["~(exists(fnGui) ? cast(string)read(fnGui, 100) : "new")~"] with output :");   
    a.foo();

    // Provide mechanism to change object
    foreach(k, v; iGui._Creators)
    {
        if (k == a._getID) continue;
        writeln("Would you like to change to "~k~" [y/n]"); if (readln()[0] == 'n') continue; 


        // Set a to new object type, assume no data
        a = v(null);
        std.file.write(fnGui, a._getID); 
        writeln("Changed to "~k~"");
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyways, maybe someone has some useful ideas to get me in the right direction?

Here's a few:

- Check out [Object.factory](http://dlang.org/phobos/object.html#.Object.factory), which allows creating a class using only its fully-qualified name.
- You can use `typeof(this)` in mixin templates, which means you don't need to pass the type of the current object to the mixin as a parameter.
- I don't see any reason for `static interface iStaticFactory`, since you can have multiple `static this` per class.
- Unless your program uses only one thread, `shared static this` would be more appropriate, as it will register the components at program start, rather than at each thread's start.

> I also think that there is probably some way to handle the saving and restoring of data easier but I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

I've just finished an overhaul of [my persistence module](https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/master/sys/persistence.d), perhaps you can find something useful there (see the unittests for usage examples).

Comment: Thanks. the istatic interface is used so that the static this is not overridden unintentionally. If the class is meant to have a static this and it doesn't register the class then the class can't be used in creating itself. Using the interface just makes sure the handlers is always registered.

Comment: I do not think object.factory helps here because it does not give the ability to initialize the object and also probably uses the GC to create the objects.

Comment: You can have as many static constructors in a class as you want. They will not override or conflict with each other, and will run in the order that they are declared. `Object.factory` calls the class's default constructor, which can do any initialization you need.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that about the static this. I do not want default construction. I pass a string, which holds the data from disk to persist the state of the object. When ever the object is created it's data is loaded and when done it is saved(or whatever mechanism is used). The data itself defines which object to load though. Basically I'd have to use load the data, get the id, use Object.factory to create the instance, then setup the instance with the data. In this case I just load the data and create/setup the instance, which hopefully can be reduced all into one template call in the future.

Comment: `iGui a = iGui.New(exists(fnGui) ? cast(string)read(fnGui, 100) : null);` is the line I am talking about. The file contains the data, in this case nothing(null) but I could add that relatively easy(unlike Object.factory which would require a second step). At some point I'd like to essentially serialize it and make better use of loading. I'm also hoping that eventually I'll be able to intelligently know how to load data through some context sensitive mechanism so automatic saving and loading of state is possible.

Comment: I could use Object.factory and instead of New, use "Initialize" or some serialization mechanisms which would be equivalent but I think more work at the object initialization site(have to create and initialize in multiple calls instead of just one) and would force GC dependence.